# Hardened BitTorrent? DoS vulnerabilities?

Tags: denial-of-service, udp, bittorrent

Is there much information about hardening libtorrent usage, or perhaps other bittorrent flavors?  I'm curious about denial-of-service attacks in particular.

I could narrow down the bittorrent protocol suite considerably, like probably just uTP.  All sending peers have TLS or Noise keys known in advance, so the transport layer could be encrypted and authenticated.  All peers learn which peers have which chunks through a separate authenticated channel, so the tracker would be replaced by internal tooling, and the tracker protocol is not required.